# Multiple screen support sanity check

Tags: android, screen

I have a project compiled with and targeting 1.5. I now want to support different screen sizes instead of letting android handle the scaling.

All I've done is modified my manifest to look like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

and I changed my project properties to build against the 1.6 (level 4) SDK.

That's all I need to do, right? All my layouts are using dip, so it should scale, and I don't want to mess with different size bitmaps just yet. Is it really necessary to add the:

```
<supports-screens>
```

tag to the manifest in my case? It's good to run on all screen sizes as-is, even QVGA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the documentation explicitly saying whether or not supports-screens is optional or mandatory. supports-screens has [default](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#defaults) values, and the section titled "Strategies for Legacy Applications" makes it sound (to me at least) like it would be optional if you are fine with defaults. However, it does not hurt if it is there as far as I know, so I would just put it in. Makes it easy to add attributes to it later if you need to.

Comment: Ok, if I add it, what should it look like? I want android to use my layouts (without scaling, just honor the DIP values) but I want android to scale all my bitmaps. So it looks like this will do it:

<supports-screens 
  android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" 
  />

is that good? Seems to work..

Thanks